# angularjs How can I get controller from compile html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, controller

I use $http service to get html and compile it by angular 
and I want to get controller in compile scope

here is my code

```
<!-- language-all: lang-javascript -->

var viewUrl = "/views/configWindow.html";
var that = this;
this.$http.get(url, {}).success(function(response) {
    var content = (response);
    var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('modalWindow'));
    el.html(content);
    //compile html for angular
    that.$compile(el.contents())(that.$rootScope.$new(true, that.$rootScope));


    //I want to get configController in here for init some data
    var configController = ? ? ?
});
```

file configWindow.html

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<div class="form-horizontal col-md-10" ng-controller="ConfigController as configCtrl"> 
<h2>{{configCtrl.Title}}</h2>
     ...
<div>
```